# SQL Server 2008 search double byte characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to tell which records are double byte character in SQL Server 2008?

For example, I want to query all records in Chinese, Korean and Japanese in a table if country filed is blank, how can I do it?

Your input is really appreciated.

I think I might have confused you guys. Everything is stored in nvarchar. Some records are in Chinese, some are in Korean, Some are in Spanish and more. We want to find out the Chinese, Japanese and Korean records to do something about it. Does that make sense?

Comment: If by `records` you mean `rows` then you will have double byte characters in **all** rows for a `nvarchar()` column. Both `Hello` and `你好` is stored with double byte character.

Comment: Are you asking about the old-timey 'Double Byte Character Set' (DBCS) used for Kanji and other primarily Asian languages, or MS's use of Unicode ('National Text')?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell which records are double byte character in SQL Server 2008?

You can use this - if the double-byte character cannot be reduced to a single byte, then you have CJK in the record:

```
select * from tbl
where convert(nvarchar(max),convert(varchar(max),somecolumn)) != somecolumn
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, then it could be as simple as a stored proc like this:

```
DECLARE @SearchString nvarchar(MAX)
...
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Country = '' and SearchField = @SearchString
```

This assumes that SearchField is `nvarchar`.

If you have a nvarchar column then all information in there will be double byte.

If you are trying to find all columns that are of type nvarchar then you can use the query below:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(col.OBJECT_ID) as [TableName], col.[name] as [ColName], typ.[name]
FROM sys.all_columns col
INNER JOIN sys.types typ
ON col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
WHERE col.user_type_id = 231
```

Comment: I think by "double byte char" he means UNICODE/`nvarchar`, since those  take twice the data space per character.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too.  Do you read the question the same way I do?

Comment: I think he wants to know how to tell which fields are `nvarchar` as opposed to `varchar`, i.e. which can support UNICODE characters.

Comment: @JNK @Abe The question is about "records" not tables/columns, so I suspect it relates to stored data.

Comment: Abe, as I changed in my post, everything is store in nvarchar. We need to identify CJK (Chinese, Japanese, Korean)records.